# Complex contour integral evaluation 2

Tags: contour-integration

> $$\int_0^1  \frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx$$

I thought of solving the problem by using $|z|=1$ and indenting the singularity around $z=1$.

Or can we use log trick (as used in $-\infty$ to $+\infty$) problems in order to solve this? in yes then $\log x$ can be taken as the branch cut. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "log trick". Could you elaborate ?

Comment: Log trick is a method used when the replication condition cannot be satisfied and we introduce a singularity and draw a contour around that to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Hint (no complex contour). Note that
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx=\lim_{s\to 1^-}\int_0^s\frac{-\ln (1-t)}{t}dt$$
and for $t\in [0,1)$,
$$\frac{-\ln (1-t)}{t}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{t^{k-1}}{k}.$$

Comment: (+1) This is how I would approach this. You are forcing me to investigate another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the series for $\log(1-x)$ as Robert Z does, we can also use the series for $\frac1{1-x}$ and integrate by parts ($u=\log(x)$ and $\mathrm{d}v=x^k\,\mathrm{d}x$):
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\log(x)\,x^k\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k+1}\int_0^1x^k\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps a [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function) approach. Under the change of variable $x \mapsto 1-x$, the integral becomes
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx = - \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 - x)}{x} \, dx.$$
And from the definition of the dilogarithm function, namely
$$\text{Li}_2 (x) = - \int^x_0 \frac{\ln (1 - u)}{u} \, du,$$
we have
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx = \left [\text{Li}_2 (x) \right ]^1_0 = \text{Li}_2(1) - \text{Li}_2(0).$$
Since $\text{Li}_2 (1) = \zeta (2) = \dfrac{\pi}{6}$ and $\text{Li}_2(0) = 0$, this gives
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6},$$
as expected.

Failing that, you could always crash this small pea under foot with a sledgehammer using an approach based on the derivative of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) as follows. From the definition for the beta function we have
$$\text{B}(x,y) = \int^1_0 t^{x - 1} (1 - t)^{y - 1} \, dt.$$
Observing that
$$\partial_x \text{B}(x,y) = \int^1_0 t^{x - 1} \ln t (1 - t)^{y - 1} \, dt,$$
we see that
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln t}{1 - t} \, dt = \lim_{y \to 0^+} \lim_{x \to 1} \partial_x \text{B}(x,y).$$
Thus
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx = -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \lim_{x \to 1} \partial_x \text{B}(x,y).$$

Since
$$\text{B} (x,y) = \frac{\Gamma (x) \Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (x + y)},$$
where $\Gamma (z)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), on taking the logarithm before differentiating with respect to $x$ we have
$$\partial_x \text{B}(x,y) = \text{B} (x, y) \left [\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma (x)} + \frac{\Gamma'(x + y)}{\Gamma (x + y)} \right ] = \text{B}(x,y) [\psi (x) - \psi (x + y)].$$
Here the result $\psi (z) = \Gamma'(z)/\Gamma (z)$ where $\psi (z)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) has been used. It follows that
\begin{align*}
\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx &= - \lim_{y \to 0^+} \lim_{x \to 1} \text{B}(x,y) [\psi (x) - \psi (x + y)]\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \text{B}(1,y) [\psi(1) - \psi(1 + y)].
\end{align*}

The $y$ limit takes a little more effort to evaluate and pays to consider it carefully. Since
$$\text{B}(1,y) = \frac{\Gamma (1) \Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (1 + y)} = \frac{\Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (1 + y)},$$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx &= -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{\Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (1 + y)} [\psi(1) - \psi (1 + y)]\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\Gamma (1 + y)} \cdot \lim_{y \to 0^+} \Gamma (y) [\psi(1) - \psi (1 + y)]\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \Gamma (y) [\psi(1) - \psi (1 + y)]\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{\psi(1) - \psi (1 + y)}{1/\Gamma (y)}.
\end{align*}
The limit is now indeterminate and of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ and can be found by applying l'Hôpital's rule. Doing so yields
\begin{align*}
\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx &= -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{-\psi^{(1)}(1 + y)}{-\Gamma'(y)/\Gamma^2 (y)}.
\end{align*}
Here $\psi^{(m)} (x)$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) of order $m$ and the following result for the derivative of the digamma function has been used
$$\psi^{(m)}(z) = \frac{d^m}{dz^m} \psi (z).$$

As $\psi (x) = \Gamma' (x)/\Gamma (x)$, we can write
\begin{align*}
\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx &= -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{\Gamma (y) \psi^{(1)} (1 + y)}{\psi (y)}\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^+} \psi^{(1)} (1 + y) \cdot \lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{\Gamma (y)}{\psi (y)} \\
&= - \psi^{(1)}(1) \cdot \lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{y \, \Gamma (y)}{y \, \psi(y)}.
\end{align*}
Now since
$$y \Gamma (y) = \Gamma (1 + y),$$
and from the [functional relation equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization) for the digamma function, namely 
$$\psi (1 + y) = \psi (y) + \frac{1}{y},$$
we can write
\begin{align*}
\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx &= - \psi^{(1)} (1) \cdot \lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{\Gamma (1 + y)}{y \, \psi (1 + y) - 1} = \psi^{(1)}(1).
\end{align*}

The value for $\psi^{(1)}(1)$ can be found from the [series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Series_representation) for the polygamma function. Since
$$\psi^{(m)} (z) = (-1)^{m + 1} m! \sum^\infty_{n = 0} \frac{1}{(z + n)^{m + 1}},$$
setting $m = 1$ and $z = 1$ gives
$$\psi^{(1)}(1) = \sum^\infty_{n = 0} \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} = \sum^\infty_{n = 1} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6},$$
where the value for the last sum comes from the well-known [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). Thus
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \, dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6},$$
as found before.