# Integration evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{e^x-1}\mathrm{dx}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

can I evaluate this integration ?

> $$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{e^x-1}\mathrm{dx}$$

how?
thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Khaled Yes, you can evaluate this integral with some time, but also a clear-phrased question that *shows effort*. Please provide some context - what did you do to solve this question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: thanks a lot ,well I tried  to solve this in Complex field  because I tried to find the series 1/n^3 but sorry I faild

Comment: according to this  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99843/contour-integral-for-x3-ex-1

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{e^x-1}\mathrm{dx} 
&= \int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^2e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\mathrm{dx} \\
&= \int_0^\infty\mathrm{dx}~ x^2e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-nx}  \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-(n+1)x}\mathrm{dx}  \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^3}\Gamma(3) \\
&= \color{blue}{2\zeta(3)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach which avoids series and is based on the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).

We begin by rewriting the integral as
$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{e^x - 1} \, dx = \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^2 e^{-x}}{1 - e^{-x}} \, dx.$$
Now as the polylogarithm function of order zero is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values)
$$\text{Li}_0 (x) = \frac{x}{1 - x},$$
if $x$ is replaced with $e^{-x}$ in the above expression, we have
$$\text{Li}_0 (e^{-x}) = \frac{e^{-x}}{1 - e^{-x}},$$
and the integral can be rewritten in terms of the polylogarithm function as
$$I = \int^\infty_0 x^2 \text{Li}_0 (e^{-x}) \, dx. \tag1$$

As the derivative for the polylogarithmic function of order $s$ is given by
$$\frac{d}{dx} \text{Li}_s (x) = \frac{\text{Li}_{s - 1} (x)}{x},$$
one has
$$\frac{d}{dx} \text{Li}_s (e^{-x}) = - \text{Li}_{s - 1} (e^{-x}),$$
and we immediately see that
$$\int \text{Li}_s (e^{-x}) \, dx = - \text{Li}_{s + 1} (e^{-x}) + C. \tag2$$

We now make use of (2) and repeatedly integrate (1) by parts. Doing so yields
\begin{align*}
I &= 2 \int^\infty_0 x \text{Li}_1 (e^{-x}) \, dx \quad \text{(by parts)}\\
&=  2 \int^\infty_0 \text{Li}_2 (e^{-x}) \, dx \quad \text{(by parts again)}\\
&= 2 \, \text{Li}_3 (1).
\end{align*}

Making use of the following [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions)
$$\text{Li}_s (1) = \zeta (s), \quad s > 1,$$
where $\zeta(x)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) we finally obtain
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{x^2}{e^x - 1} \, dx = 2 \zeta (3).$$

Comment: Why do you bother with $\text{Li}_s(z)$ instead of expanding $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ directly ? In your other [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2556664/276986) you use even more special functions.

Comment: I bother since the approach used here with polylogarithms is more general. In fact, the polylogarithmic approach allows one to find the indefinite integral, something not possible with the expansion method. Here $$\int \frac{x^2}{e^x - 1} \, dx = -2 \text{Li}_3(e^{-x}) - 2x \text{Li}_2 (e^{-x}) - x^2 \text{Li}_1 (e^{-x})$$ Often where integrals of this type arise is in the study of blackbody radiation. Here integrals on a finite interval (say $[a,b]$ where $0 < a < b < \infty$) in addition to those on the interval $(0,\infty)$ are needed with the former being found in terms of polylogarithms.